# window.opener is not working in Facebook App on the iOS devices

Tags: javascript, html, ios, facebook

In the Facebook app, I have created a fb page in that added a test button with my URL. When we click on that button it loads my page test1.html in the new tab with the app. 
In that page test1.html page, I have a button for login, now when I click on that login, it will open a child window test2.html, after the OAuth has done, it closes the child window and comes to the parent window. This is the flow.

For communicating child window to parent window I'm using window.opener which works everywhere except in the facebook app on the iOS device.

Code:  test1.html

```
 var Login  = (function() {
 var events = function() {
               $('#login_button').off('click').on('click', function() {
                newWindow("/login.do");
               });
             }
 var newWindow = function(url) {
                  window.open(url,'Oauth',"width=600,height=600");
                 }
 var customerDetails = function(resp,callback) {
                        console.log(resp);
                        if(callback && typeof(callback) ==="function"){
                           callback();
                         }
                        }
})();
```

Code: test2.html

```
 var self_close = function() {
                        self.close();
                     } 
  window.opener.Login.customerDetails(message,self_close);
```

when I print window.opener, it's throwing null. Any help would be appreciated